# Get each first level li

Tags: jquery, each

I have this list

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <ul>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

I need to get only the first level lis

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you use the direct child selector?

```
$("body > ul > li")
```

That should only return li tags that are direct children of the ul, whereas this:

```
$("ul li")
```

would return all descendant li tags and it would find li descendants under all levels of ul.

This whole selector would work a lot better if you put an ID on the UL that you want to get the first level li tags in.  Then, your selector could be this:

```
$("#myID > li")
```

and it would be independent of where in your DOM it was located (whereas the first one has to be a direct child of the body tag to work).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the first `ul` is a direct child of `body` you can use this selector:

```
$('body > ul > li');
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to keep it as general application as possible:

```
$('ul').filter(function(){
    return ($(this).closest('li').length == 0);
}).children('li');
```

Either answer from @Kokos or @jfriend00 are great. The only issue is if the `<ul>` is not a direct descendant of the `<body>`.

If this is a one-time scenario, perhaps post a bit more about it, and we can specify; otherwise without knowing more about the document structure, round-a-bout generalization (*see above*) attempts need be made.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the Kokos and jfriend00 answers you can use:

```
$(selector).children();
```

To select just direct childs of selector. If you have that HTML selected in your selector already, just take its children.